# Arduino compiler gives "system cannot find the file specified" error

Tags: arduino

I've been working with an Arduino Uno board and the Arduino IDE for a couple of weeks now without any problems. Yesterday I tried to compile the following snippet:

```
#include <Servo.h>
//www.elegoo.com
Servo myservo;

void setup(){
  myservo.attach(3);
  myservo.write(90);// move servos to center position -> 90°
} 

void loop(){
}
```

When I open `Servo.h` (in the library created by the install) there are several includes, which reference header files in sub-directories within the Servo folder (ie. `#include "avr/ServoTimers.h"`). These files are where I would expect them to be. There is one reference to `#include inttypes.h`. I can NOT find that file within any of the Arduino library directories.

Does anyone know where that file should be or how I can get it?

Comment: Try asking at [arduino.se].

Answer (score 0):

I did a little more digging and found the file in   `..\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include`. I copied that file along with its dependent *include* (stdint.h) into the Servo library directory. The snippet now compiles.

Not sure why the compiler can't find other files included in the install!